# How to install older version of node in Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I downloaded a package from https://nodejs.org/dist/.
I tried running the Application file Node.exe but it just opens terminal and does nothing.

But I couldn't figure out how to install after downloading.

I'm doing this as after I uploaded Node to v12.18.1, npm install doesn't work and gives me error saying

`npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Using [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) should make it really easy to handle multiple node versions on the same system.

Comment: node got installed by nvm, but doesn't show up on running any node commands

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Install the version of Node.js you need.
2. List node.js installatios using nvm:

   **nvm ls**
3. High chance the version you installed is also listed
4. Select the version to use using nvm

   **nvm use**